# Android Sqlite display random row

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm currently developing an app. What it does, the user would input some sentences and then the app will get the ambiguous word and then display it meaning. In my table I have fields like _id, word, meaning, definition_number.

Sample data: 
_id    word    meaning                             definition_number 
1     Break    to pause from something    1 
2     Break    to cut into pieces                2

If the user would input: My break was very fast. 
The intended output would be:
**Ambiguous word:** Break 
**Meaning:** To pause from something

I want to display the it randomly. This is a snippet of code from my **DBHelper.class**:

```
        public Cursor getAllWords()
{
    Cursor localCursor =   
            //this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
            //      KEY_ID, KEY_WORD, KEY_MEANING }, null, null, null, null, null);//"RANDOM()");
        //this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
        //      KEY_ID, KEY_WORD, KEY_MEANING }, null, null, null, null, "RANDOM()", " 1");
            this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
                            KEY_ID, KEY_WORD, KEY_MEANING }, 
                            null, null, null, null, "RANDOM()");
    if (localCursor != null){
      localCursor.moveToFirst(); 
    }

    return localCursor; 


}
```

**MainActivity.class**:

```
    ArrayList<String> colWords = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> colMeanings = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] words;
String[] meanings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initControls();

}

private void initControls() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    text = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);

    view = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

    clear = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);

    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text.setText("");
            view.setText("");

        }
    });


    connectDB();

    ok = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Log.d(strWord, strWord);

            strWord = text.getText().toString();
            if(strWord.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input some data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
            checkAmbiguousWord();
            }
        }   
    });
}

private void connectDB(){
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);

    try {

            dbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

            dbHelper.openDataBase();

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

            throw sqle;

    }

    cursor = dbHelper.getAllWords();




    /*strWord = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_WORD))
            + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_MEANING)); */

    colWords.clear();///added code
    colMeanings.clear();///added code
    /*
    for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        colWords.add(cursor.getString(1));
        colMeanings.add(cursor.getString(2));
        String records = cursor.getString(0);

        Log.d("Records", records);
    } */

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                colWords.add(cursor.getString(1)); 
                colMeanings.add(cursor.getString(2));   
                String records = cursor.getString(0);

                Log.d("Records", records);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

}

private void checkAmbiguousWord(){
    final String textToCheck = text.getText().toString();
    List<Integer> ambiguousIndexes = findAmbiguousWordIndexes(textToCheck);
    view.setText(!ambiguousIndexes.isEmpty() ? 
            ambigousIndexesToMessage(ambiguousIndexes) : "No ambiguous word/s found.");
}

/**
 * @param text checked for ambiguous words
 * @return the list of indexes of the ambiguous words in the {@code words} array          
 */
private List<Integer> findAmbiguousWordIndexes(String text) {
    final String lowerCasedText = text.toLowerCase();
    final List<Integer> ambiguousWordIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    words = (String[]) colWords.toArray(new String[colWords.size()]);
    meanings = (String[]) colMeanings.toArray(new String[colMeanings.size()]);

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (lowerCasedText.contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
            ambiguousWordIndexList.add(i);
        }
    }
    return ambiguousWordIndexList;
} 

public String ambigousIndexesToMessage(List<Integer> ambiguousIndexes) {
    // create the text using the indexes
    // this is an example implementation
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Integer index : ambiguousIndexes) {
        sb.append("Ambiguous words: ");
        sb.append(words[index] + "\nMeaning: " + meanings[index] + "\n");
        sb.append("");
    }
    return sb.toString(); 
}
```

But all it does is displaying the two records. Both id 1 and id 2. I just want to display only one record randomly. I really need help regarding this. Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You have `RANDOM()` ordering but you also need to add a `LIMIT 1` to only return one result row. There's an [overload of `SQLiteDatabase.query()` that takes in a limit parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
                        KEY_ID, KEY_WORD, KEY_MEANING }, 
                        null, null, null, null, "RANDOM()", "1");
```

Comment: I've tried this but when I input a sentence wherein there are two ambiguous words, only one record is displaying? And the random is not doing its thing.